# Append to start of filename

Tags: windows, script, batch, rename

I'm trying to add the word [Replay] to all mp3 files in a folder using a batch file like so:

```
@echo off
for %a in (c:\folder\*.mp3) do ren %a [Replay]%a
```

But it wont rename the files.

all the examples i tried from googling appends the word but runs over the next characters in the filename, i just need to add the word to the start without running letters over.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are three problems with your batch file:

- In batch files, you have to use `%%a` instead of `%a`.
- `%%a` will hold the full path, not just the filename.
- The rename will fail if there are spaces in the filename.

In general, I'd also recommend leaving `echo` on while troubleshooting.

Try this instead:

```
cd /d c:\folder
for %%a in (*.mp3) do ren "%%a" "[Replay]%%a"
```

If that renames the files twice, `for` is reading the directory entries as it goes. As a workaround, you can save the list in a temporary file:

```
cd /d c:\folder
dir /b *.mp3 > temp
for /f "delims=" %%a in (temp) do ren "%%a" "[Replay]%%a"
del temp
```

Comment: Thank you Dennis, your method works..although, it adds the word twice.."[Replays][Replays] bla bla.mp3...i tried "move" instead of "ren" but same result..

Comment: Interesting. It behaves differently on my machine. That might depend on the version or on the number of files.

Comment: Trying your workaround now...i'm using Windows Server 2012

Comment: Yup..it worked..maybe it is infact the windows version and how it behaves with ren command. Thank you my friend! :)

Comment: You're welcome! It's `for` that behaves differently. It doesn't read the directory contents at once, so it effectively finds renamed files twice.

Comment: Simple FOR iterations can be affected by the DO clause. FOR /F cannot be affected by DO clause. You can avoid the temp file by using FOR /F to process the DIR command: `for /f "eol=: delims=" %%a in ('dir /b *.mp3') do ...`. I added EOL=: to guard against file names that start with `;`, though I doubt you will ever run into one :)

Comment: @dbenham: *FOR /F cannot be affected by DO clause.* I'm 99% sure you're right. But since my machine behaves differently than the OP's, it didn't want to risk it.