# Rename Files In A Batch Script

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file

I'm attempting to rename all files in a folder via a batch script but I'm getting an incorrect syntax error that I can't seem to identify:

```
for %%f in (%Source%\*DebugLog.Config) do %%f ren %%f "%Source%\%ProjectName%.*DebugLog.Config"
```

The idea being that I prefix any file that ends in DebugLog.Config so that it becomes "projectName.DebugLog.Config"

Where is this going wrong?

Comment: Please state clearly your goal. You did not identify a criterium to rename files (names must be unique per folder). Asterisks you used don't make sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### I'm getting an incorrect syntax error that I can't seem to identify

```
for %%f in (%Source%\*DebugLog.Config) do %%f ren %%f "%Source%\%ProjectName%.*DebugLog.Config".
```

There are several mistakes in your batch file (2 of which I made myself).

As pointed out to me in [comments](https://superuser.com/questions/1006821/add-text-to-end-of-multiple-filenames/1006862#comment1393944_1006827) [elsewhere](https://superuser.com/questions/1006821/add-text-to-end-of-multiple-filenames/1006862#comment1393963_1006827) by [dbenham](https://superuser.com/users/109090/dbenham):

> The REN target cannot include drive or path. It must be name and extension only
>
> Use of the simple FOR runs the risk of renaming a file more than once - not good :-( Better to use FOR /F with DIR /B

See his answer [add “text” to end of multiple filenames](https://superuser.com/a/1006862/337631) for more explanation on the above.

In addition `do %%f` is meaningless, it should be just `do`.

Here is a working batch file:

```
@echo off
pushd %source%
for /f "delims= eol=:" %%f in ('dir /b /a-d *DebugLog.Config') do ren "%%f" "%ProjectName%.%%f"
popd
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [dir](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) - Display a list of files and subfolders.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [popd](http://ss64.com/nt/popd.html) - Change directory back to the path/folder most recently stored by the PUSHD command.
- [pushd](http://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html) - Change the current directory/folder and store the previous folder/path for use by the POPD command.
- [ren](http://ss64.com/nt/ren.html) - Rename a file or files.

Answer (score 0):

This is going wrong in more than one place.
Assuming `%Source%` ends in a backslash (edit: it seems it doesn't, so adding the backslash:)

```
for %%f in (%Source%\*DebugLog.Config) do ren "%%f" "%ProjectName%.%%~nxf"
```

The ren target mustn't contain a path, so `%%~nxf` extracts Name and Extention of `%%f`.