# Add 1 character at the start of each filename

Tags: batch-rename

I want to put 1 character at start  of each jpg filename.
I have made this batch file:

```
for %%A in (*.jpg) do ren "%%~A" s"%%~nA%%~xA"
```

This works almost perfectly, but the first file is processed twice:

```
ssNL201501
sNL201502
sNL201503
```

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### This works almost perfectly, but the first file is processed twice

```
for %%A in (*.jpg) do ren "%%~A" s"%%~nA%%~xA"
```

You need to use:

```
for /f %%A in ('dir /b *.jpg') do ren "%%~A" s"%%~nA%%~xA"
```

As [dbenham](https://superuser.com/users/109090/dbenham) explains in his answer to [add “text” to end of multiple filenames](https://superuser.com/a/1006862/337631):

> Note that it is critical that you use `FOR /F` and not the simple `FOR`. The `FOR /F` gathers the entire result of the `DIR` command before it begins iterating, whereas the simple `FOR` begins iterating after the internal buffer is full, **which adds a risk of renaming the same file multiple times.**

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [dir](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) - Display a list of files and subfolders.
- [for](http://ss64.com/nt/for2.html) - Conditionally perform a command on several files.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.