# How to add a prefix to all files and folders in a folder? (windows)

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-rename

The following command only changes the name of the files but not the folders.

`for %a in (*) do ren "%a" "00_%a"`

Comment: Do you absolutely have to use a batch file? Can you not use a program like Rename Master to do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### The following command only changes the name of the files but not the folders.

```
for %a in (*) do ren "%a" "00_%a"
```

Notes:

- Using `for` as above is not advised.
- There is a possibility that files can be renamed multiple times.
- See below for the reason why.

---

Use the following in a `cmd` shell:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %a in ('dir /b') do ren "%a" "00_%a"
```

In a batch file (replace `%` with `%%`):

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b') do ren "%%a" "00_%%a"
```

Note:

> It is **critical** that you use `FOR /F` and not the simple `FOR`.
>
> The `FOR /F` gathers the entire result of the `DIR` command before it begins iterating, whereas the simple `FOR` begins iterating after the internal buffer is full, which adds a risk of renaming the same file multiple times.

as advised by [dbenham](https://superuser.com/users/109090/dbenham) in his answer to [add "text" to end of multiple filenames](https://superuser.com/a/1006862/337631):

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [dir](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) - Display a list of files and subfolders.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.

Answer (score 0):

To perform this For loop on folders (directories) instead of files, simply include the `/D` switch.

`for /D %a in (*) do ren "%a" "00_%a"`

From `for /?`:

> FOR /D %variable IN (set) DO command [command-parameters]
>
> ```
> If set contains wildcards, then specifies to match against directory
> names instead of file names.
> ```

Comment: `ren` does work on folders. The limitation is that "you cannot specify a different drive or path for the Target.

Comment: @DavidPostill Yeah it was an old habit creeping in, I changed it back to `Ren`.

Comment: You can do both files and folders in one command (see my answer). And I suspect `for /d` may also have the problem of trying to process values multiple times  (also see my answer).