# How to add a prefix to all folders and sub-folders? (windows)

Tags: windows, batch-rename

re: [How to add a prefix to all files and folders in a folder? (windows)](https://superuser.com/questions/1028054/how-to-add-a-prefix-to-all-files-and-folders-in-a-folder-windows)

I am trying to create a .bat file which will rename a predefined folder structure with a project number prefix eg. project name/admin - becomes - 7000-01 project name/7000-01 admin. Here is what I have so far:

```
@Echo off
pushd
for /d %%g in (*) do ren "%%g" "7000-01 %%g"
```

Which works only for the top level but I would like it to rename all sub-folders (including those below the 'admin' level in the eg. above.)

I read here - https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html that using `for /d /r` should work to recursively rename all sub-folders, but I cannot get it to work.

FYI the `pushd` is used so the .bat name stays the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were so close! The correct command is:

```
for /r /d %%g in (*) do ren "%%g" "7000-01 %%~ng"
```

---

**Full explanation:**

As you mentioned, you must use `for /d /r` to work recursively. (https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)

Checking the syntax of the `ren` or `rename` command reveals that a very specific syntax is required:

```
>ren /?
Renames a file or files.

RENAME [drive:][path]filename1 filename2.
REN [drive:][path]filename1 filename2.

Note that you cannot specify a new drive or path for your destination file.
```

Your original command inside the for loop was evaluating to `ren "FULL_PATH" "FULL_PATH"`, and it should actually be `ren "FULL_PATH" "SIMPLE_FILE_NAME"`

To get the file name without extension or path, use `~n` with the variable (https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly and I think I understand why, bonus!