# Batch FOR loop not working

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, batch

So I am trying to a procedure of converting images in a directory, but it just doesn't run at all, and I fail to see what's incorrect in my batch code:

```
FOR /R %a in (*.png) DO (
    files\pngnq -s 1 -n 16 %~fa 
    ren *nq8.png "%~na.png"
    files\gimconv "%~na.png" --format_style psp --format_endian little --pixel_order faster --image_format index4
    del "%~na.png"
    )
```

the error it outputs is in french "in was not expected" (in était inattendu).

EDIT: this is the orginal (working code) code:

```
set file=*.png
files\pngnq -s 1 -n 16 %file% 
ren *nq8.png 12345.png
files\gimconv 12345.png --format_style psp --format_endian little --pixel_order faster --image_format index4
del 12345.png
ren *.gim READY4BIT.gim
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### I fail to see what's incorrect in my batch code:

```
FOR /R %a in (*.png) DO (
    files\pngnq -s 1 -n 16 %~fa 
    ren *nq8.png "%~na.png"
    files\gimconv "%~na.png" --format_style psp --format_endian little --pixel_order faster --image_format index4
    del "%~na.png"
    )
```

I can see two obvious issues with the above code:

1. In a batch file you need to replace `%` with `%%` (in a batch file use %%a, in a `cmd` shell use `%a`)
2. There is a possibility some files may get processed twice, so you should use `for /f` together with `dir`).

There may be other things wrong as well, but I don't have the required programs to test it.

Use the following batch file instead:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b *.png') do (
    files\pngnq -s 1 -n 16 %%~fa 
    ren *nq8.png "%%~na.png"
    files\gimconv "%%~na.png" --format_style psp --format_endian little --pixel_order faster --image_format index4
    del "%%~na.png"
    )
```

Note:

> It is **critical** that you use `FOR /F` and not the simple `FOR`.
>
> The `FOR /F` gathers the entire result of the `DIR` command before it begins iterating, whereas the simple `FOR` begins iterating after the internal buffer is full, which adds a risk of renaming the same file multiple times.

as advised by [dbenham](https://superuser.com/users/109090/dbenham) in his answer to [add "text" to end of multiple filenames](https://superuser.com/a/1006862/337631):

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [dir](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) - Display a list of files and subfolders.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.

Comment: Thank you for the clarafication, but your code is half working, it doesn't take the name of the file, it take the first line of the result that `dir` gives you, the *volume of disk D: is named blabla*

Comment: Oops. Small mistake. My apologies. We need to add `/b` to the `dir` command. Answer updated.

Comment: That's great! ;)